# Preg replace pattern for PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Im trying to make a preg-replace pattern to convert the text "orderId" into "order-id".

```
$argumentName = "orderId";
$argumentName = preg_replace("/([A-Z])/e", "-strtolower($1)", $argumentName);
echo $argumentName;
```

The output for this line is "order0d". Why is this not working?

Comment: I don't really see how your regex relates with your text. Is this the only case you are looking for? If so then some simple string manipulation would suffice.

Comment: `-` is an [arithmetic operator](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic) and `strtolower` is a function that returns a string. You should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense for me to use a regex like this. The whole thing could be replaced by search for I, replace with -i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're specifying that your replacement-string is an expression, this:

```
strtolower($1)
```

is `'i'` (as it should be), and this:

```
-strtolower($1)
```

is `-'i'` ("negative `'i'`"), which forces the string `'i'` to be interpreted as a number — `0`.

What you want is

```
$argumentName = preg_replace("/([A-Z])/e", "'-' . strtolower($1)", $argumentName);
```

which concatenates the strings `'-'` and `'i'`.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `/e` at all?

```
$argumentName = strtolower(preg_replace("/([A-Z])/", "-$1", $argumentName));
```

This places a dash before any uppercase letter, and then lowercases the entire string.